# Unit Tests under VS2012 Fail: CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView returns null

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, collectionviewsource

I have recently attempted to upgrade a solution from VS2010 to VS2012, and as part of that I have introduced the new [.runsettings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx) to generate code coverage results.

In order to specify the run settings file I have had to un-select the .testsettings file that was working in VS2010.  As soon as I do this and run my tests, a large number of them start to fail because the `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` method returns null instead of the expected default view.

If I re-select the old .testsettings file then my tests all pass, but the code coverage settings are incorrect.

Has anyone else experienced similar problems with the upgrade?

Comment: Follow up: it appears that this is limited to a single project - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what the problem was: one of the unit tests was manually restarting the `Dispatcher` as part of some cleanup, and that worked fine in VS2010 but not in VS2012.

I guess this is pretty specific to the one solution, but it might provide a clue to anyone that finds this.